# Installing a python package in a ruby application

Tags: heroku

I have a ruby sinatra app, and in one place I need to call out to a python script -- using ruby's `system()` -- and that python script depends on a python package.

Python3 is pre-installed on heroku (I checked by looking at one of my existing ruby apps), but my question is: How can I install both ruby gems for my main app and the python package needed for the python script?

Obviously installing the gems is just done using the `Gemfile`, and if I was writing a pure python application I would use `requirements.txt`, but I'm unclear how to proceed in this case where I need both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [multiple buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app) in your application. Briefly:

1. Add a `requirements.txt` file (or `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`) to your root directory containing your Python dependencies
2. Set your Ruby buildpack explicitly:

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
   ```
3. Add the official Python buildpack before the Ruby buildpack (your main buildpack should be last):

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/python
   ```

Now, redeploy your application.